# Error while creating new organization (Deployment Manager)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

While creating a new organization via Deployment Manager, I am facing the following error:

> Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportDefaultDataAction failed.
>   Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the
>   post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting
>   for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have
>   timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The
>   duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was -
>   [Pre-Login] initialization=105; handshake=13532; [Login]
>   initialization=0; authentication=1; [Post-Login] complete=136426; The
>   wait operation timed out

I tried google, but failed to find any solution with this specific error while creating an organization.

**My (Test) Environment**

- Windows 7 (Host)

  - VMWare Workstation 10.0 with 1 GB memory and 1 core (Guest)

    - Windows Server 2012
    - SQL Server 2012
    - Dynamics CRM 2013 trial (downloaded from Microsoft website)

Comment: Have you tried with a higher spec VM? The specs of your VM look too low to have SQL Server and CRM Server running.

Comment: Yes, I tried after upgrading my machine from core 2 duo to core 2 quad. Uninstalled CRM setup and re-installing again. With core 2 duo it took 1 hour to appear the error message while creating organization from setup. But after processor upgrade it seems bottle-necked for more than 2 hours with the same screen and doesn't throw any error until the power cut off :(. I will show you the exact screen shot, after reaching home, where it is hanging and seems to be busy in some loop.

Comment: will paste the sql server log entries for that time period also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for replying too late.

It was a performance issue and got resolved by upgrading

- processor to Core 2 Quad
- RAM up to 6GB

VMware Workstation settings:

- 2GB memory
- 2 cores

Also apply VMware performance tweaks if required:
[Top 10 VMware Performance Tweaks](http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_increase_vmware_performance.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [modifying the ExtendedTimeout property](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918609/en-us)?  You may want to modify the OLEDBTimeout as described in the article, but it sounds like your problem is with the ExtendedTimeout setting.

I also agree this may be a server resource issue.  You may want to get this working on a higher spec machine before using a low performing VM.